# Catch-all exception handler in Grails

Tags: grails

How can I install an exception handler in Grails which catches all exceptions which propagate to the user?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can override the exceptionHandler bean using resources.groovy with your own class that extends GrailsExceptionResolver

e.g.

```
beans = {
    exceptionHandler(com.yourapp.YourExceptionHandler){
        // this is required so that calls to super work
        exceptionMappings = ['java.lang.Exception': '/error'] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To clarify the solution for everyone, `exceptionHandler` will override the `GrailsExceptionResolver`